# Problem with html dom, how to get the height of p tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tags

lets say we have the code below:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="paragraph">
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
    dfsdfdsfdsfsdfsd<br />
    sadadsadsad<br />asdsadsadsadsadsadsad<br />
    asdsadsadsadsadsad
    </p>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById('paragraph').offsetHeight);</script>
    </body></html>
```

If in a p tag exists:

> `<h1></h1> or <h2></h2>...`

it does not return the actual height of the p tag

jquery `($("#paragraph").height())` returns `0`, so does

```
document.getElementById('paragraph').offsetHeight
document.getElementById('paragraph').style.height
```

How to fix this? Is this a bug or not?

I have test it on ubuntu with firefox, chrome, opera (latest versions) and does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't valid for an `<h1>` element to be a descendant of a `<p>` so the browser is moving it out, leaving the `<p>` empty, giving you the 0 height.

The resulting markup in Safari looks like this:

```
<p id="paragraph"></p>
<h1>HELLO</h1>
dfsdfdsfdsfsdfsd<br>
sadadsadsad<br>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad<br>
asdsadsadsadsadsad
<p></p>
```

Comment: @loannis - Browsers attempt to correct invalid markup. Unclosed tags, improperly placed tags, and so on. They do their best to guess at the best correction, but it doesn't always turn out the way you may hope. Ultimately, you just need to remove the `<h1>` from inside the `<p>`, or change it to a `<div>`.

Comment: I think thats stupid. Why i cannot insert <h1> inside <p> and i can in a <div>???

Comment: It's the fundamentals of the DOM structure - consult the W3C standards for more information - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html

Comment: Conceptually: because a `<p>` is a paragraph. How can you put a heading inside a paragraph? Technically: because `<p>` is an element with an optional end-tag, so if the parser sees a new block-level element it guesses you have simply omitted the `</p>`, as was the most common practice back in the HTML 2.0 days and still widespread. Otherwise the blocks would pile up and you'd be left with a hundred nested `<p>` tags by the end of the page. HTML parsing is full of ‘convenience’ quirks like this; if you need it more predictable, you have to use XHTML.

Comment: xm, it seems i cannot also insert <div> in <p>. Is there a reference on what elements are allowed inside <p>???

Comment: @loannis - Here's the reference I was looking for. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3 *"The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."* @bobince has a nice explanation above.